# Add language to keyboard without opening settings

Tags: android, kotlin

There's application which restricts users from opening the settings, if they tries to open settings it show login screen which he'll need to put password for managers of the app.
Now I need to add feature that makes him able to add `language` without opening settings. Specifically add Arabic language to the `keyboard`.

All I got from search that I can translate the app to another `language` or start intent to the specific page of adding `language` which is restricted as it belongs to settings package.

There's possible way to do that? by writing directly to the settings?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the phone's Locale programmatically by this,

```
Locale locale = new Locale(language);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
```

But it will only work above API level 16.
An also after changing that you might need to change the screen configuration to apply the changes to your app.